Where to obtain fastq_illumina_filter
I'm setting up a snakemake pipeline for my lab, and I'd like to install fastq_illumina_filter. All links I can find point to this address for info on it, but the website seems to be down.
Is there anywhere else I can get the tool from? Or is there a new tool that does the same thing I could use instead?

I found this site after Googling fastq_illumina_filter and comparing the file name to that shown in an archived version of your link: https://www.sigenae.org/drap/install.html
Direct link to tool tarball: http://genoweb.toulouse.inra.fr/~ccabau/fastq_illumina_filter-0.1.tar.gz
This seems to work.

The Genoweb Toulouse link seems to work :) thanks!
